# Увеличить размер шрифта поочерёдно

Tags: css

Как увеличить размер шрифта поочерёдно? Например, у меня есть 4 тега `<p>` с текстом внутри. Я хочу, чтобы у первого элемента размер шрифта был 10, у второго 12, и третьего 14 и так далее. Чтобы для каждого следующего элемента шрифт увеличивался на 2.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-size

Comment: а известно сколько их будет ?

Answer (score 3):

Поддерживаю ответ shugich.

Предлагаю еще вариант ниже. Особенности:

1) без JS;

2) размер шрифта указан в em, а не в px;

3) лаконичный CSS;

4) минус — нельзя указать шаг изменения в px, потому что размер шрифта вложенного блока здесь вычисляется в em, т.е. по сути, в процентах от размера шрифта родителя;

5) еще минус — в таком варианте ноль семантики. Поэтому если у вас реально абзацы текста, а не просто оформление, то так делать плохо.

```css
body {font-size: 16px;}
div {font-size: 1.1em;}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
  <div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
    <div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
      <div>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
        <div>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
          <div>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: При такой структуре можно увеличивать на два пикселя вообще без проблем: https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/LymRLW

Comment: @shugich Как? :) Я что-то не поняла из Вашего примера. Там не текст, а кнопка.

Comment: Ох, прошу прощения. Случайно дал не ту ссылку. Вот: https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/oWdzEe

Comment: @shugich Круто! Не знала про calc. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ:

```css
p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 14px;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 16px;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
```

Но у этого способа всё плохо с динамикой. Если элементов станет больше или захочется изменить шаг, то придется все вручную каждый раз дописывать.

Есть решение на JavaScript:

```js
function formatText(fontSize, step) {
  var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  paragraphs.forEach(function(p) {
    p.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
    fontSize = fontSize + step;
  });
}
formatText(12, 2)
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
```

У этого решения тоже есть минус. Текст обработается только после загрузки страницы. Может произойти неприятный «скачок».

Я еще представляю, что можно до загрузки страницы формировать необходимые размеры на PHP (если вы пользуетесь PHP, конечно). Но в таком случае надо смотреть контекст.